# How to add image logo in the end of video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Can we adding image(logo) to end of video?. I already found the way add logo 5second before video played with delayed the video?

Material:
video file = af.flv ( format can be changed, avi or mp4 is okay )

image file = bg.png

```
ffmpeg -itsoffset 5 -i af.flv -r 25 -loop 1 -i bg.png -filter_complex "[1:v] fade=out:125:25:alpha=1 [intro]; [0:v][intro] overlay [v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -acodec copy out.mp4
```

Tried search on internet and read about documentation but no luck. Is there anyway adding Image(logo) 5 seconds after video END?

Comment: Possible dupe: [Append JPG to MPG Video ffmpeg/mencoder](http://superuser.com/questions/540330/append-jpg-to-mpg-video-ffmpeg-mencoder)

Comment: Possible dupe: [Building video incrementally from incoming jpeg images](http://superuser.com/questions/88343/building-video-incrementally-from-incoming-jpeg-images)

Comment: @techie007 sorry but no... I have af.flv and bg.png, I want to joining this 2 file.

Comment: Aside from image and/or video file format, how is your question different than the ones I pointed out?

Answer (score 1):

You want to concatenate. Three methods are available- demuxer filter and protocol; and filter would usually work for you.

See this:

http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files

You could create a movie file from the image file first, of appropriate duration. Of course, the issue with filter concatenate is that audio and video streams have to match, which means you might have to mux in a wav (?) file to the end logo movie file.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, Rajib. Please, when linking to other sites, also include at least an example of a command and the essential information here. Thanks!